# Why am I only getting a 4MB/s read and write speed from my SSD?

Tags: ssd, sata, file-transfer, storage

My computer has only one storage drive and that is a 256gb SSD (SATA) which I've made partitions on.

I tested my max drive speed and it is about 350MB/S (read and write). Though, when I copied a stack of folders from one partition to another I was only getting 4MB/s of copy speed.

My computer is 11 years old and below are the specifications-

1.Intel Dual Core Pentium 2.60 GHz

2.4gb RAM

3.256gb SSD (SATA)

What exactly is the problem? Is there  problem with the SATA cable?

More Info-
I upgraded to this 256gb SSD from a 500gb HDD which I was previously using.

Comment: What do the "stack of folders" contain? If you are transferring very small files then the source drive may be spending more time seeking for data than actually reading or writing. Even for SSDs copying tiny files is inefficient. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHNwV.jpg note that random 4k reads only manage 25MB/s and that several random reads may be needed for a single 1-4kB file, and then another couple potentially for the writing. I would expect closer to your benchmark speed for multi gigabyte files though.

Comment: @Mokubai Well I figured the problem out, it was due to the fact there where a ton of small files in those folders.